# SQL stored Procedure - Convert date format

Tags: oracle, date, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table with multiple columns. One among those is a date column with DATE format as

```
TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

Now I want to copy this date to another table but after changing the date format to

`YYYY - MM - DD HH:MM:SS`

How can I conver Date from one date format to another in Oracle stored procedure?
Is their any specific function to do so?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Actually DATE datatype is not stored formatted in Oracle database, you set formatting options when quering it via NLS_PARAMS or explicit conversion. So what is your destination column datatype? As long as source column has time zone information what will be time zone of destination column? You need to know it for correct conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
try with
TO_TIMESTAMP(date-string,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```